Plot hole in "Tribulations of a Chinaman in China"
I am reading this Verne's classic, but I noticed there is a plot hole. By the way, this question obviously contains spoilers.
In the book the insurance agent Mr. Bidulph states that the contract is void if a beneficiary of the contract takes Kin-Fo's life. However, Kin-Fo tells Wang the philosopher (a beneficiary) to kill him...
Interestingly, searching in the internet I read one version of the book where these lines are omitted. Is there indeed a plot hole or am I missing something?

Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please add which versions or translations of the book you read, including the version on the web ("in the internet I read one version of the book ...")?
